# how to use articles correctly?can someone where to use article in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

Alizay is most intelligent girl in school.
How to add articles to this sentence?
can someone tell where to use articles in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Saqib, you are welcome to this site.

Intelligent is an adjective. Most intelligent is the superlative form of this adjective. you need to put the definite article "the" before this form of adjective. So the correct sentence is:

Alizay is the most intelligent girl in school.

Answer (score 1):

I think correct places for articles in this sentence are like this:

`Alizay is the most intelligent girl in the school.`

1) The first `the` uses with a superlative adjective.

2) The second `the` uses with a particular place(school).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these thumb rules for general article usage. They should hold well for almost all cases, with a few exceptions though.

1. **a** is used before words beginning with a consonant (or consonant sound)

   Examples:

   > I own **a** car which was manufactured in India

Also, there could be a case like so

> There is **a** university down the road.

Here, even though the first letter is **u**, the pronunciation is as **Yoo**, hence we use **a** instead of **an**.

2. **an** is used before words beginning with a vowel (or vowel sound)

Examples:

> This is **an** old movie

Or

> He is holding **an** umbrella

3. **The** is used when you are referring either to specific things, which have already been mentioned in the conversation beforehand, or to things regarded as unique or even when you are using superlatives (like in your case)

Examples:

> I know **a** doctor who lives here. **The** doctor's wife is **an** artist. (Doctor has been Already mentioned and we are referring to the same doctor now)

Or

> **The** Earth revolves around **the** Sun (Unique Objects)

Or

> He is **the** tallest in his class. (Superlative)

For more insight into this, visit [this](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm) link.
Cheers! And always remember:

**An** apple **a** day keeps **the** doctor away. ;)